# moment js array format

Tags: jquery, json, momentjs

I have a moment object with the date formatted, but the _a(array) is actually returning the format in all integers, see below.

```
_a: Array[7]
0: 2014
1: 2
2: 22
3: 0
4: 0
5: 0
6: 0
length: 7
```

My question is it at all possible to have the month actually set as the name string of the month?

Edit: Here is the moment call I make and this is what is returned in the array

```
moment(datetoformat, "ddd MMM DD");
```

Comment: Can you show us how are you creating the formatted date array? http://momentjs.com has some examples on the homepage that show you how to get `January` or `Jan` etc

Comment: moment(datetoformat, "ddd MMM DD");

Comment: The `_a` variable is part of the *internal* structure of a moment.  You should not be consuming it directly.  Pretend it doesn't exist.  It's hard to answer your question because you aren't showing what value is in `datetoformat`, nor are you showing an example of what output you're actually looking for.  Please edit your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know its late, but i was on the same problem lately
It's simple and straightforward use`toArray()` function

```
moment().toArray()
```

it will return an array like this :

```
[2014, 6, 20, 18, 21, 55, 285]
```

Comment: Note: **months** are **zero-indexed**, so January is month 0